# Environment specific Capefile capistrano3 rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano3

I have rails 4.1 app and multistage (staging, production) deployment with capistrano3.

I want to deploy it to one stage server (which use rvm) and one production server (which use ruby env)

By default everything works nice on production server, but without rvm1-capistrnao3 gem installed and included in Capefile I cannot deploy to staging.

Is there a way to require 'rvm1/capistrano3' in Capefile, only if I deploy to staging like that

`cap staging deploy`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've done to fix it

I made default capistrano multistage setup, like Doug Hall said!

The tricky part is the way to include rvm1-capistrano3 in Capefile

See deepak's workaround here https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/issues/49

So instead of just `require 'rvm1/capistrano3'` in Capefile, do it like that

```
task :use_rvm do
  require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
end

task 'staging' => [:use_rvm]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run cap install, it creates a file called config/deploy.rb and two files in the config/deploy directory: production.rb and staging.rb. Use the config/deploy.rb file for all settings that both the production and staging servers have in common. Use the other two for the respective settings on those machines. I would require 'capistrano/rvm' in your Capfile, but only use it in the config/deploy/staging.rb file. Capistrano executes the common config/deploy.rb FIRST, then calls the proper staging.rb/production.rb file, so all set  values from config/deploy.rb are available in the staging.rb/production.rb file.

Comment: but when I require 'rvm1/capistrano3' in Capefile, this broke my production settings... and cap production deploy die with following error `Can not find rvm in '/home/user/.rvm'.`

Comment: I am looking for way to use rvm1-capistrano only when deploy to staging. Or ignore it somehow in config/production when deploy to production

Comment: I assume the /home/user/.rvm it's looking for is on your production machine, and not your local (development) machine, right? I actually use rbenv on all my (local/staging and production) machines. However, when listing the Capistrano gems in the :development group of my Gemfile, I pass "require: false" like this:

      gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0', require: false